# Round dataframe pyspark only columns that is DoubleType

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the follow function:

```
def round_df(df_input: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    for c in ([f.name for f in df_input.schema.fields if isinstance(f.dataType, DoubleType)]):
        df_output = df_input.withColumn(c, round(sf.col(c), 3))
    return df_output
```

I need round the columns in df that are DoubleType, but when apply this function in my df pyspark don't work. Can anyone see my error?

Comment: Can you share more of the error you're receiving? It might be that you have forgotten to import the function round, if youve imported functions as F then you will need to write F.round() for example

Comment: There isn't errors, only don't work. The output return without any round

Comment: I tried @FJ_OC but, don't work :\

Comment: the function does not work because you're resetting the variable with every iteration. e.g. in first iteration a `df_output` is created using `df_input`. then in the second iteration, you are not using the previously created output, but you use the original df which has original structure (all unrounded fields)...

Comment: Can you help writing the code fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to use `.dtypes`.

```py
data_sdf. \
    select(*[func.round(k, 2).alias(k) if typ == 'double' else k for k, typ in data_sdf.dtypes])
```

The aforementioned rounds only the fields that are of double type and leaves the rest as is.

Comment: But, I need that are a function, because I will use in anothers dfs in code

Comment: you can use this one-liner and create a function as well. keep updating the `data_sdf` (or change it to your `df_input`).